# OpenCMS edit button overlap completely

Tags: opencms

```
1: <cms:contentload editable/>
2: <cms:contentload editable/>
```

there are two of `<cms:contentload>` in one jsp page.
The problem is, the edit button of first `<cms:contentload>`, instead of staying at the tag, has been positioned to the second `<cms:contentload>` tag. and overlay completely.

Answer (score 0):

First, the edit button don't work in tables. Now i think may be will be your html divs. The Edit button is displayed in the first div you find
supose

```
<div>
   [...]
   <cms:contentload editable="true">
    [...]
    <div>
      [...]
      <cms:contentload editable="true">
       [...]
      </cms:contentload>
    </div>
   </cms:contentload>
 </div>
```

also check you css